# How did Satoshi Nakamoto create the first Bitcoin? The Genesis Block

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, block, satoshi-nakamoto

How did Satoshi Nakamoto create the first Bitcoin? I have never read any statement where he recommends specific tools like CGMiner. You can't mine with the Bitcoin Core software. Actually, Bitcoin Core should be able to do that. What's the point if I have Bitcoin Core to transfer Bitcoin but no Bitcoins can be created with it?

What software did Satoshi use to mine???

Comment: The point of bitcoin core is to make sure that no one is cheating you with fake bitcoin code. Proof of work secures this on a data propagation level and doesn't require that everyone participates in it to work, only requires that there is a dense amount of decentralized miners keeping the hashpower extremely high.

Comment: The "first Bitcoin" was not in the genesis block.

Answer (score 4):

> You can't mine with the Bitcoin Core software.

You can't now but you could with early versions of the software.

The facility, for mainnet, was removed because CPU and GPU mining were no longer feasible due to the rise of ASICs. It is still possible in testnet etc.